# interaction of 2 classes

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Airport
    
  attr_reader :plane
    
  CAPACITY = 20  

  def initialize
    @plane = []
    @capacity = CAPACITY
  end

  #can land a plane
  def land(plane)
    fail 'plane is full' if  @plane.count >= @capacity
    @plane << plane
  end
        
  def take_off
    fail 'weather is stormy' if @weather
        
    @plane
  end
   
  def weather
    @weather = weather   
  end
end

class Weather
  def stormy?
    [true, false].sample
  end
end
```

I am new to Ruby. I am a little confused in how to use the method of the `Weather` class in my `Airport` class.

I want the `take_off` method in my `Airport` class to fail when the weather is reported to be stormy. I am unsure where to begin in understanding object interactions. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: To interact w/ an object you need an object. To instantiate an object you write `TheClass.new(any, params, needed, if_any)`. Stefan's answer is the non-TL;DR version (although I might provide a default `Weather` implementation, and maybe use a keyword parameter).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `fail` if weather is stormy, you have to call its `stormy?` method:

```
def take_off
  fail 'weather is stormy' if @weather.stormy?

  # do something
end
```

But in order to get the above working, `weather` needs to be an instance of `Weather`. I would simply pass it to the constructor. In addition, I would make it a settable attribute, so you can easily update it:

```
class Airport
  attr_accessor :weather
  attr_reader :plane

  CAPACITY = 20

  def initialize(weather)
    @weather = weather
    @plane = []
    @capacity = CAPACITY
  end

  # ... 
end
```

I would also make the weather a little more deterministic, e.g. by having a [wind force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale) attribute:

```
class Weather
  attr_reader :wind_force

  def initialize(wind_force)
    @wind_force = wind_force
  end

  def stormy?
    wind_force >= 10
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
weather = Weather.new(3)

airport = Airport.new(weather)

airport.take_off # no exception

airport.weather = Weather.new(12)

airport.take_off # RuntimeError: weather is stormy
```

Comment: Thank you. This is starting to be a bit clearer but I find that I am still having issues with the take_off method would I still write 'fail 'weather stormy" if '@'weather.  As it still will not allow me to type '@'weather.stormy?  and if I leave it as '@'weather  and then use wather = Weather.new(3) it returns my fail error message of "weather is stormy"

Comment: @hibscodes _"will not allow me to type `@weather.stormy?`"_ – what happens if you do so? Do you get an error messages or unexpected behavior?